# I keep getting this error java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am getting a `NoSuchElementException` which is probably due to `Scanner` and I get it after I add a student and go back to the menu.

My main method:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    static ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static Student s = new Student();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }
    
    public static void menu() {
        System.out.println("       ***Students Manage***\n");
        System.out.println("1 - Insert a student");
        System.out.println("2 - Display students");
        System.out.println("3 - Remove student\n");
        option();
    }
    
    public static void option() {
        int option;
        
        do {
            System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
            option = scan.nextInt();    
        }while(option < 1 || option > 3);
        
        switch(option) {
            case 1: 
                s.addStudent();
                students.add(s);
                break;
            case 2:
                showAllStudents();
        }
        menu();
    }
    
    
    private static void showAllStudents() {
        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            students.get(i).toString();
        }
    }
}
```

My Student method:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {
    
    String name;
    int studentNumber;
    static int count = 1;
    int yearNumber;
    
    public Student() {
    }
    
    public void addStudent() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        LocalDate year = LocalDate.now();
        yearNumber = year.getYear();
        studentNumber = count++;
        studentNumber += yearNumber * 10000;
        System.out.print("Enter the student name: ");
        name = scan.nextLine(); 
        
        if(name == null || name.trim().equals("") || !name.contains(" "))
        {
            do{
                if(name.trim().equals("")){
                    System.out.print("Please enter a valid name.\nEnter your name: ");
                } else if(!name.contains(" ")) {
                    System.out.print("You should write at least 2 names(name and surname).\nEnter your name: ");
                }
                name = scan.nextLine(); 
            }while(name == null || name.trim().equals("") || !name.contains(" "));                  
        }
        scan.close();
        System.out.println("The student "+name+" was added to the student list "
                + "and his/her student number is "+studentNumber);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return name+" - "+studentNumber;
    }
}
```

The error that I'm getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:937)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
  at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
  at StudentSchool.Main.option(Main.java:29)
  at StudentSchool.Main.menu(Main.java:21)
  at StudentSchool.Main.option(Main.java:40)
  at StudentSchool.Main.menu(Main.java:21)
  at StudentSchool.Main.option(Main.java:40)
  at StudentSchool.Main.menu(Main.java:21)
  at StudentSchool.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in how you're using `Scanner`.  The first is that you are opening a second `Scanner` on `System.in` while you have one already open and reading from it.  This produces strange results due to buffering.  You should create and use only a single `Scanner` object that you never close.  You can do this by passing the `Scanner` you create in your `main()` method into your `addStudent()` method so that it can use that same Scanner instead of creating and later closing a new one.  So...

```
public void addStudent(Scanner scan) {
    // Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ....
    // scan.close();

....

public static void option() {
    ....
    s.addStudent(scan);
    ...
```

When you do this, a second problem will arise.  When you mix calls to `nextInt` and `nextLine` on a Scanner object, you run into a problem where `nextInt` only reads the numeric digits from the input stream, but leaves the newline character produce by the user hitting Return.  When you then call `readLine`, it reads that newline that's already on the input stream, so instead of waiting for your input, it reads an empty line as the next result.  To avoid this problem, you should add an extra call to `readLine` right after you call `readInt` to consume this stray newline character. So...

```
System.out.print("Choose an option: ");
option = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
```

Making these two changes should cause your program to behave as you desire.